# Installing SDK and NDK to start coding android apps with python

Tags: android, python, eclipse, ubuntu, android-ndk

http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toolchain/#introduction

Please do not mind because this not really related to SO. I aint getting replies in askubuntu that is why I am posting this question. Please do answer. it will be much appreciated.

refer the link above, I downloaded the SDK and the NDK, i run the SDK manager and I installed the required files. This is enough as a platform right? or I need to download ADT or eclipse? 
I installed cython also as given in the doc. What I want to know it, if I install eclipse, which version should I first download? because there is no eclipse in particular for python.

Secondly, after setting up any platform(in my case, its just SDK manager, not eclipse) it says 
'after installing them export both installation path, NDK version and API to use' what does it even mean?

I remember, before installing or running sdk manager, I opened .bashrc file, put up 2 lines, 
export path=$path:......android-sdk
export path=$path........android-ndk
saved it. 
I do not know whether the SDK manager started working because of that, but it works and my emulator also works after creating a vew avd.

I am totally stuck at the exporting of installation paths, versions and apis. Where do I export them to? 
And if you go futher down, you can also see 'configure youre path to add android binary:' what does this mean? I have a ubunu 12.04, I need to set environment variables?

Then further down, it says 'USAGE', 
    ./distribute.sh -m "kivy"

When i run it, it says distribute : no file or directory. Well, I have just downloaded kivy and extracted I havnt done anything more to it. What am I supposed to do. Please help me here. I really need it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't give all the details on the individual bits of the build process you might have done wrong, but rather than doing things this way you can use the [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) tool. If you follow the instructions to install it, it automatically downloads and links all the dependencies (including sdk/ndk/python-for-android/python/kivy), reducing the build process for a kivy app to a single command.

> Then further down, it says 'USAGE', ./distribute.sh -m "kivy"
>
> When i run it, it says distribute : no file or directory. Well, I have just downloaded kivy and extracted I havnt done anything more to it.

You would need to run that command from within the directory where you unpacked python-for-android. There would be a file in that directory called 'distribute.sh'.

Also, you don't need to download kivy yourself, python-for-android does this automatically as part of its distribute process. You *do* need to install your own version of kivy to use it locally, which I assume you've already done?

I assume you are making a kivy app? That is what these instructions are designed for.